# How to use Axios with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, web-scraping, axios

I'm trying to perform web scrapping through web scrapping API's. For using the API, it's mandatory to some extent to use axios. Now I'm unable to find a way to use axios with web editor.

I tried the given method and the code always returns null.

1. Go to the Axios repository on GitHub at https://github.com/axios/axios.
2. Click on the "releases" tab and download the latest release of the library as a zip file.
3. Extract the zip file to a folder on your computer.
4. In the Google Apps Script editor, create a new script file by clicking on the "+" icon next to "Files" in the left sidebar.
5. Name the file "axios.gs".
6. Copy the contents of the "dist/axios.min.js" file from the folder you extracted in step 3 and paste it into the "axios.gs" file in the Google Apps Script editor.
7. Save the "axios.gs" file.

```
const query = 'site:linkedin.com/company "' + 'Company Name' + '"';

  const options = {
    token: "223E9D905C2BC87EBD5181677A8C240A",
    url: 'https://www.google.com/search?q=' + encodeURIComponent(query)
  };

  axios.get("https://scraperbox.com/api/scrape", options)
    .then(response => {
      Logger.log(response.data)
    }).catch(error => {
      Logger.log(error.response.data.errors || error)
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I also tried to bypass `UrlFetchApp.fetch` with `axios`. I changed your code to:

```
async function fetchtest(refresh) {
  const url = `https://randomuser.me/api/`
  await axios.get(url)
    .then(response => {
      Logger.log(response)
    }).catch(error => {
      Logger.log(error)
    });
}
```

And it works but I got error:

```
There is no suitable adapter to dispatch the request since :
- adapter xhr is not supported by the environment
- adapter http is not available in the build
```

So [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) is unavailable, [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) also unavailable. [`http`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#httpgetoptions-callback) from Node also unavailable.

There is nothing else available from ES6, so we forced to use `UrlFetchApp.fetch`.